# Highlight recent points (+ notify on response to comments + list comments below questions & answers)

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications, recent

Sometimes I see my rating has gone up (or down even), and I go straight to my stats page to see which question/answer got a vote.

But it's not very easy to see...  it kind of requires remembering how many votes all of my existing posts previously had (which is bizarrely easy to do actually).

One solution would be that for any questions or answers where your points have changed since last looking at this page,  the associated number would be in a different colour, say red.

It would probably be nicer if this colour was based on the time since the point was awarded, and fades from red back to its current colour over the period of a day or two.

However, not all points are based on questions and answers. It is also possible to gain points for comments.   maybe it would make sense to display a **third category** under **questions** and **answers** entitled **comments**?   sometimes I add a comment to ask for clarification, and it would be very helpful to be able to reference that comment to check whether someone has replied.

In fact it would be really nice to get a notification if someone replies below any of my comments that contains a '?' (or revises the associated question/answer).  SO could then  notify me as 'possible answer to a comment'.   And it would be nice if comments could be nested in a tree structure,  but that is another issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. comments do not confer rep
2. use the `/reputation` route if you want to track rep changes in minute detail, or check http://stackapps.com for an application that does this for you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are referring to your [user profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152664/ohmu).

Have you seen your [Recent Activity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/152664) page?  It shows you a summary of your recent activity as well as mentions.  You can also adjust the time period the summary shows you.

Comment: @Ohmu, if I interpreted your post wrong, let me know and I'll deleted my answer.